# How to see rails console active record errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, digest, rails-console

When I try

```
2.1.5 :013 > User.create(id: 999999, first_name: 'bob', login: 'smithb',
last_name: 'smith', email: 'testuser@test.com', active: true)
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
```

I get

```
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #<User id: nil, login: "smithb", password_digest: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, first_name: "bob", last_name: "smith", email: "testuser@test.com", roles: nil, active: true>
2.1.5 :014 > User
 => User(id: integer, login: string, password_digest: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, first_name: string, last_name: string, email: string, roles: integer, active: boolean)
```

How can I see what error caused the rollback?

I can see the validators in the model and I believe I have all the required field so trying to find out exactly what the error is

User model is

```
2.1.5 :015 > User
=> User(id: integer, login: string, password_digest: string, created_at: datetime,
updated_at: datetime, first_name: string, last_name: string, email: string,
roles: integer, active: boolean)
```

Update - it was Digest that I needed.  I'd still be curious to know how to see that error.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this way:

```
@user = User.create(id: 999999, first_name: 'bob', login: 'smithb',
last_name: 'smith', email: 'testuser@test.com', active: true)
```

Check errors and validity:

```
@user.errors
@user.errors.messages
@user.valid?
```

Comment: This solution is for the controller, not the rails console as his question asked.

Comment: I couldn't agree. This solution works in both controller and console. There is nothing wrong with this solution working on console.  Learn more.

Comment: what do you mean ?  who told you there are no instance variables?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `!` to create.

```
 User.create!(id: 999999, first_name: 'bob', login: 'smithb', last_name: 'smith', email: 'testuser@test.com', active: true)
```

Comment: This is not the good way, this will through exception which isn't necessary.

Comment: Don't make confusion unless you are too good with anything. This solution works fine on both side!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid save rather than `ActiveRecord` auto rollback when the validation failed, you must do `new` on the object

```
2.1.5 :013 > user = User.new(id: 999999, first_name: 'bob', login: 'smithb', last_name: 'smith', email: 'testuser@test.com', active: true)
2.1.5 :014 > user.valid?
2.1.5 :015 > true/false
2.1.5 :016 > user.save
```

on line `015` if its `false` then

```
2.1.5 :016 > user.errors #will show if any errors
```

> TIP

`create` will fire save i;e after `new` then `save` and 
`save!` will directly throw `ActiveRecord` errors if any

Hence the better way would be

```
 > user = 2.1.5 :013 > User.new(id: 999999, first_name: 'bob', login: 'smithb', last_name: 'smith', email: 'testuser@test.com', active: true)
 > if user.valid?
 >  user.save
 > else
 >  "throw some error"
 > end
```